Is cohomology group corresponding to wedge product preserved under homotopy?
The explicit question is below:
For de Rham cohomology, wedge product $(u, v) \rightarrow u \wedge v$ gives a homomorphism of cohomology groups, i.e. $H^k(M) \times H^l(M) \rightarrow H^{k+l}(M)$. When we consider another smooth manifold $N$ which is homotopic equivalent to manifold $M$. It is known that the differential form pullback from $M$ to $N$ is in the same cohomology class. But what about their wedge product? Is the image of their wedge product $u \wedge v$ pullback to manifold $N$ the same cohomology class corresponding to this map $H^k(N) \times H^l(N) \rightarrow H^{k+l}(N)$ when we also pullback $u$ and $v$ to manifold $N$ and use this map of cohomology groups? (i.e. there is a commutative diagram)
Edit: Thanks for Katz's comment. The usual homotopy equivalence might not have a pullback, so here we consider a special homotopy equivalence: the retraction map. In this case, the pullback could be defined by an inclusion map.

There is a slight technical problem here in that manifolds $M$ and $N$ could be homotopy equivalent, or even homeomorphic, without being diffeomorphic.  In the absence of a diffeomorphism, pullback of differential forms is undefined.  So while cohomology rings are still isomorphic by general de Rham theory (passing via singular cohomology for example), this cannot in general be done at the level of differential forms even if both manifolds are smooth.  However, if one has a diffeomorphism between them, this certainly establishes an isomorphism at the level of cohomology rings (and even at the level of the complex of differential forms!).

Perhaps worth pointing out, given how the question is worded, that (a) the statement "the differential form pullback from $M$ to $N$ is the same cohomology class" is nonsense even when pulling back along a diffeomorphism since there's really no a priori way to identify classes on $M$ and $N$ and, moreover, even if $M = N$ a diffeomorphism need not induce the identity on $H^*(M)$; and (b) that the wedge product is the product in the cohomology ring.

@BenSteffan, I understood the question to inquire what happens if we identify the cohomology groups by isomorphisms furnished by the diffeomorphism: are the cup-products respected under such?  Note that if we have homotopy equivalences which are smooth without being diffeomorphisms, this may not be completely trivial and may require the general theory.  Similarly, the wedge product is not really the cup-product in cohomology for the same reason, but only represents it.

I just wanted to give some more context for OP since the wording of the question seems a little misguided, say :) As for homotopy equivalences, if you know about homotopy invariance of de Rham cohomology (which OP apparently does) then it's immediate that a smooth homotopy equivalence also induces an isomorphism on cohomology rings (since it's a ring map + a group isomorphism of the additive groups).

@BenSteffan, I am not sure I follow what you are saying.  You still need to know that it is a ring map :-) Apriori if you only know that it gives an isomorphism of groups in each dimension, it would be an extra task to show that it preserves the ring structure.  For example, looking this up in Warner I see that he states the de Rham theorem on page 206 for each dimension $p$.  Thus he does not talk about the ring structure at this stage (perhaps elsewhere he does; I haven't checked carefully).

Yes, Warner does get to it by page 214.

@MikhailKatz, thanks for your comment. You're correct. I edit the question. We consider a special homotopy equivalence like a retraction map.

OK, then the answer is affirmative, as I mentioned, and follows from page 214 in Warner Foundations of Differentiable manifolds and Lie groups.

@MikhailKatz You do need to know it's a ring map, but so do you for showing that diffeomorphisms induce ring isos., and this you seemed happy to assume given in your answer, no? :) Either way, it's a direct consequence of the facts that pullbacks of forms along smooth maps commute with wedge products, and this in turn you show by manipulating the definition.
